# Changing Default Homescreen on MIUI 7

Tags: miui

This is for an Mi Pad running MIUI 7. The default home screen is the first one which allows only widgets & not apps. Googling around, several sites say that you can change the def home screen - i.e. make the 2nd or any other screen the home screen by doing the 3 finger swipe and pinch. I even found videos which show this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7QGDQTYbGw

But when I do this, it shows up other options -> Move App, Widgets, Wallpaper, Effects (this is supposed to shown for the 2 finger pinch). For me both 2 finger and 3 finger pinch brings this up.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I am not experienced in the MIUI device but one alternate method could be to download an android launcher. Launchers like Google now or nova work really well in my opinion. I know this doesn't really fix the issue but, chances are you'll like these launchers better than the default one.

Comment: Do launchers change the default screen? The first screen in MIUI is a widget screen where I cannot have any icons which did not come with the tablet.

Comment: Yes almost all of them do

Answer (score 1):

The 3 finger swipe and pinch shows your pages(all screens). And the default home screen will be in orange color at home icon. If you need to change it just tap over the `home` icon of the page that you needed. Then, it will be set as default home screen. Here, also you can drag and arrange your screens.

Comment: Did you read my question?

Comment: I am using redmi 1s, miui 7. In my device, 2 finger pinch shows, `move apps, widgets,wallpaper,effects`. And, 3 or 4 finger pinch shows all of your screens on screen.

Comment: Or just do a wipe cache. Goto Updater > Select 'Reboot to Recovery mode'(from 3 dots on top-right). Your device will boot into recovery, select language, select 'wipe &reset' and select 'wipe cache'. after that 'reboot to system'. And try again

Comment: Looks like changing home screen is not supported in Mi Pad only in Mi Phones.

Comment: Is this your post @user93353 :   http://en.miui.com/thread-270332-1-1.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still have this problem but I just experienced it today. My solution:

3 finger swipe isn't actually a swipe. I just touched 3 fingers on the screen at the same time and hold and then instead of swiping, do a closing motion towards the center. Then the screen to edit pages appears.

Comment: Do you have a Xaomi Phone or Tablet?